# I am not finding all the eigenvectors for an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Question:**

For the matrix A $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & -12 & 4 \\
    6 & -2 & -36 & 12 \\    
    0 & 0 & 5 & -2 \\
    0 & 0 & 21 & -8 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

find all eigenvector(s) for the eigenvalue λ = -2

**Answer:**

Iλ - A 
    \begin{bmatrix}
λ & 0 & -12 & 4 \\
6 & λ+2 & -36 & 12 \\    
0 & 0 & λ-5 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 21 & λ+8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
Insert λ = -2 into Iλ - A, let it be B
    \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 & -12 & 4 \\
6 & 0 & -36 & 12 \\    
0 & 0 & -7 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 21 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Solving B for reduced row echelon form

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\    
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
I get one eigenvector, that being:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\ 
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
However, the actual answer features 2 eigenvectors:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\ 
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac 27 \\
0 \\
\frac27 \\ 
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix for $\lambda I - A$ is incorrect. You failed to reverse the signs of the non-diagonal elements of $A$ when you subtracted it.

$$\lambda I - A = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    λ & 0 & 12 & -4 \\
    -6 & λ+2 & 36 & -12 \\    
    0 & 0 & λ-5 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & -21 & λ+8 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Row-reducing this with $\lambda = -2$ will give you the correct eigenvectors.

For the record, $\ker(\lambda I - A) = \ker(A - \lambda I)$, and I find it easier to work with the latter generally, as you just subtract lambda from the diagonal elements of $A$ rather then needing to negate everything.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering why I always get only 1 eigenvector when there is 2.